# Results of computing geodesics with 2D polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, geodesics

I am trying to find and solve the geodesics equation for polar coordinates. If I start by the definition of Christoffel symbols with the following expressions :

$de_{i}=w_{i}^{j}\,e_{j}=\Gamma_{ik}^{j}du^{k}\,e_{j}$

with $u^{k}$ is the k-th component of polar coordinates ($1$ is for $r$ and $2$ is for $\theta$).

Now, if I take :

$de_{r} = d\theta e_{\theta}$

$de_{\theta} = -d\theta e_{r}$

So : $\Gamma_{12}^{2} = 1$ and $\Gamma_{22}^{1} = -1$

All others Christoffel symbols seem to be zero.

Now, I can write the geodesics equation with :

$\dfrac{d^{2}u^{i}}{ds^{2}} + \Gamma_{jk}^{i}\dfrac{du^{j}}{ds}\dfrac{du^{k}}{ds}$

I get :

$\dfrac{d^{2}r}{ds^{2}} = \dfrac{d\theta}{ds}\dfrac{d\theta}{ds}\,\,\,(1)$

$\dfrac{d^{2}\theta}{ds^{2}} = -\dfrac{dr}{ds}\dfrac{d\theta}{ds}\,\,\,(2)$

By make appearing the logarithmic derivate : $\dfrac{d\,ln(u)}{ds}=\dfrac{u'}{u}$, I have :

for (2) : $\dfrac{\theta'}{\theta} = - \dfrac{dr}{ds} ; \dfrac{d\theta}{ds} = e^{-r}$

Finally, I have for (2): $\theta(s)=s\,e^{-r}$

for (1), taking $\theta(s)=s\,e^{-r}$, I have :

$\dfrac{d^{2}r}{ds^{2}} = \bigg(\dfrac{d\theta}{ds}\bigg)^{2} = e^{-2r}$

Finally, we get for (1) : $r(s)=\dfrac{s^{2}}{2}e^{-2r} = \dfrac{1}{2}\theta^{2}$

By using results from (1) and (2), I could write :

$r=\theta^{2}/2$

I don't understand this result knowing $s$ may be choose as a linear parameter or curvilinear (like the length on the geodesics).

Why don't I get simply : $s=r\theta$ ???

I don't see where I have done a mistake in my above calculus.

If someone could see what's wrong, this would be great.

Comment: I am not sure "homework" is a valid VtC reason in GR questions...

Comment: Maybe I should rather post my question on mathematics exchange

Comment: MathSE is more friendly, but there are more not so high quality questions, and they aren't physics-oriented. On my opinion, your question is quite high quality, but unfortunately there is a close vote about it, what I don't agree. I suggest, edit your question to show very clearly, that it doesn't match the following close reason: *"Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users"*.

Comment: If it will be closed, I will initiate to reopen it. After you have 300 reputation points, also you will be able to vote to reopen your own question. 5 votes are needed to reopen a question. Another idea: the voters tend to be lighter-handed with remarkable nicks as the "user?????" ones.

Comment: The Christoffel symbols are $\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^r = -r$ and $\Gamma_{r\theta}^{\theta} = \Gamma_{\theta r}^{\theta} = \frac{1}{r}$, so I get $\frac{d^2r}{ds^2} = r\frac{d\theta}{ds}\frac{d\theta}{ds}$ and $\frac{d^2\theta}{ds^{2}} = -\frac{2}{r}\frac{dr}{ds}\frac{d\theta}{ds}$

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1882436/11127

Comment: @peterh I don't see how this is any different from closing a mechanics or E&M question. In either case, the question is about checking the details of a calculation. Just because the calculation is more advanced doesn't make it "better".

Comment: @John Rennie: Thanks, I realize that I forgot to take basis vectors with the definition : $\vec{e_i}=\partial \vec{x}\,/\,\partial y^{i}$